# How to create environment variable in WildFly using Wildfly Managment?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, wildfly, jndi

I know how to create these variables in Tomcat. I put lines like

```
<Environment name="KEY1" value="VALUE1" type="java.lang.String" />
```

into `CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml`
Then I get these variables in java code using spring injection, I use `@Value(${KEY1})` annotation. 
Now I need to create same varibales in WildFly application server. How to do this? It's desirible to do using WildFly Managment

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. It can be done in Wildfly Management by path

```
Configuration -> System Properties(View) -> Add
```